Android APK not compatible
Alright, I made a few games way back in the Marshmallow era and they are still on the play store. I want to update them to work on the latest android BUT I do not have the code or project files anymore for any of the apps.
I hear you can export the APK with apktool and edit the android manifest and I did but sideloading the APK still says app not compatible. Any idea why? My updated manifest below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:installLocation="auto"
package="com.ndappsdev.card_game"
platformBuildVersionCode="34"
platformBuildVersionName="14.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="com.ndappsdev.card_game.RunnerApplication">

    <activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="com.ndappsdev.card_game.RunnerActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/menu_settings"
        android:name="com.ndappsdev.card_game.RunnerPreferenceActivity"/>
    <service android:name="RunnerBillingService"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidBrowser"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <meta-data android:name="xperiaplayoptimized_content"
        android:resource="@string/xperiaplayoptimized_content"/>
    <meta-data android:name="game_display_name"
        android:resource="@string/app_name"/>
    <meta-data android:name="game_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYUse24Bit"
        android:value="1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="OrientLandscape"
        android:value="-1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="OrientPortrait"
        android:value="-1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="OrientLandscapeFlipped"
        android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="OrientPortraitFlipped"
        android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYAmazonGameCircle"
        android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYNumExtensionClasses"
        android:value="1"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYExtensionClass0"
        android:value="MoPubExt"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYiCadeSupport"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="YYHapticFeedback"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="5077000"/>
</application>
</manifest>


"but sideloading the APK still says app not compatible" -- could you post the exact output from your sideloading operation? Note that you need to use the same signing key as you used back when you published the apps originally.

The exact error when trying to install the app using a file browser is "App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone"
Yes, I do know I need the same signing key but if I am just testing the app on my phone it shouldn't require it until I update it on the playstore unless I am mistaken.

You might try using adb install, as it may give you a more informative error message. "if I am just testing the app on my phone it shouldn't require it until I update it on the playstore unless I am mistaken" -- if you already have the Play Store build of your app installed, unless you have a separate applicationId for debug builds, any local installation will replace the Play Store build. That will require matching signing keys.

I'll try adb and see. I do not have the play store build installed. I'll also try signing with the original key. Thanks.
